# setText() is not working in android

Tags: android

Following is my code.In this, I just get the list of all running processes and get their various attributes like process name, process id and I store process ids into an `ArrayList`. Then,I found the data traffics used by all process ids using `trafficstats()`.Now, i want to show these values in the `TextView`. But, mu code is not showing these values.
Can anyone suggest me that were i am doing wrong?

I use 3 `TextView` in `activity_main.xml`.First `TextView` is showing my values but another 2 are not working.
The whole code is in the `MainActivity.java` class.

```
TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//this.setContentView(textView1);    
    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
        this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
        {
                textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString()+procInfos.get(i).processName+" "+procInfos.get(i).pid+ 
                            " " + String.valueOf(procInfos.get(i).processName.length())+"\n");
                //if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.camera")) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera App is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //}
                a1.add(procInfos.get(i).pid);

        }

        for(Integer a2 : a1){
            long re = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(a2);
            long sd = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(a2);

            arr1.add(a2);

            System.out.println("Recieved Bytes: "+re/1000 + "Send Bytes: "+sd/1000);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(re));
            textView3.setText("ABAABABBA");

        }
```

Here is the activity_main.xml class:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This is my whole MainActivity.java class:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static ArrayList<Integer> arr1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //this.setContentView(textView1);        


    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
            this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
            {
                    textView1.setText(textView1.getText().toString()+procInfos.get(i).processName+" "+procInfos.get(i).pid+ 
                                " " + String.valueOf(procInfos.get(i).processName.length())+"\n");
                    //if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.camera")) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera App is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //}
                    a1.add(procInfos.get(i).pid);


            }

            TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            for(Integer a2 : a1){
                long re = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(a2);
                long sd = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(a2);

                //arr1.add(a2);

                System.out.println("Recieved Bytes: "+re/1000 + "Send Bytes: "+sd/1000);


                textView2.append(""+Long.toString(re));
                textView3.append("ABAABABBA");
                textView3.invalidate();

            }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Thanks all the people who gave me suggestions.My problem is solved now.
Thanks everyone for this quick response.

Comment: Are you able to print this log... System.out.println("Recieved Bytes: "+re/1000 + "Send Bytes: "+sd/1000);

Comment: try this `textView2.setText(String.valueOf(re));`

Comment: add all value on for statement and set to TextView after for.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a layout problem? Maybe textView2 and textView3 are just collapsed or invisible. Can you post activity_main.xml?

Comment: add the activity_main.xml code

Comment: instead of ..setText(textView2.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(re)  , try textview.append(" "+ String.valueOf(re))

Comment: Can you give some more context on MainActivity.java? Is the code you posted inside onCreate()? And can you post the complete method?

Comment: And what happens if you temporarily remove the calls to textView2.setText(...) and textView3.setText()? Do textView2 and textView3 display the text "TextView", which is assigned in activity_main.xml or do you just see nothing?

Comment: @legr3c i m posting the whole MainActivity.java class...

Comment: @legr3c yes, i am getting the default text of the textViews.

Comment: Thanks @legr3c  Code is working now.

Comment: Great! You should post the solution in an answer and accept it.

Comment: @legr3c actually, i am new and i don't know where to post the answers.

Comment: At the very bottom of this page :)

Comment: @legr3c i am getting one more problem. trafficstats is not showing me the correct values. It is showing 0 for both sending and receiving values.

Comment: That sounds a bit like a separate problem so you might want to consider opening a new question for that.

Comment: @legr3c can you help me in this question???

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067291/trafficstats-getuidrxbytes-giving-0-for-all-processes

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method `invalidate()` after each `setText("")` to see the changes in the UI

**Example:-**

```
TextView text1.setText("dummy text");
text1.invalidate();
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

outside your `for loop`. No need to use `findViewById()` in each iteration.

By the way, better to use [Log.d()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) than System.out.println() in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);       
for(Integer a2 : a1){
    long re = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(a2);
    long sd = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(a2);
    arr1.add(a2);
    System.out.println("Recieved Bytes: "+re/1000 + "Send Bytes: "+sd/1000);
    textView2.setText(textView2.getText().toString()+Long.toString(re));
    textView3.setText("ABAABABBA");

}
```

Comment: I used it. But problem is still there. Not getting even text in textView3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in every new iteration of loop you are creating new textview, so initalize both textviews outside the loop

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

it may help

Comment: I try this also. But, still not getting the values in textView

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

is not in right place, just move them to this first line.
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for this quick response.
In actual, all the textViews were placed so far from each other thats why i was not able to see all the values and also i used

```
textView3.append(Long.toString(sd)+"KB");
```

to show the values.